# Problem with recover info from firestore and send it to my bot in DialogFlow

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I wrote this piece of code to make a marketplace bot with dialogflow. I also created a simple database to save informations about my user's actual shopping cart on firestore. But, when i run this function on Inline Editor, my bot only answers "Seu carrinho: " and nothing about the info i recovered. The info appears correctly in firestore console, showing that the retrieval of information is correct. I think that its a problem about async functions that i dont understand. Help?

```
function myfunction(agent){

     var opt = agent.parameters.number;

    if(opt == 1){
      agent.add(`Ver estoque`);
    }else if(opt == 2){
      agent.add(`Seu carrinho: `);

      const carrinho = db.collection('/Usuarios/Usuario1/Carrinho');
      var produtosCarrinho = carrinho.get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
            agent.add(`${doc.id} - ${doc.data().Quantidade} ${doc.data().Bloco} - ${doc.data.Preco}\n`);
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }else{
      agent.add(`errou`);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the collection path is correct? It seems that you are trying to get a subcollection, but I can't be sure without the data strucure. If I'm right, something like:

```
function myfunction(agent){

     var opt = agent.parameters.number;

    if(opt == 1){
      agent.add(`Ver estoque`);
    }else if(opt == 2){
      agent.add(`Seu carrinho: `);

      const carrinho = db.collection('Usuarios').doc('Usuario1').collection('Carrinho');
      var produtosCarrinho = carrinho.get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
            agent.add(`${doc.id} - ${doc.data().Quantidade} ${doc.data().Bloco} - ${doc.data.Preco}\n`);
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }else{
      agent.add(`errou`);
    }
  }
```

should work.
I think that just removing the first slash like this:

```
const carrinho = db.collection('Usuarios/Usuario1/Carrinho');
```

will work too

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call `carrinho.get().then(...).catch(...)` returns a Promise, which you store in `produtosCarrinho`, but you don't do anything with this Promise.

Most importantly, since this is part of an Intent Handler, you need to return this Promise to the Handler Dispatcher. This is so it knows to wait for the Promise to be fulfilled (ie - it calls the function in the `then()` portion) before it sends the reply back to the user.

So what is happening is that you're starting the database call, but your function almost immediately finishes and returns before the call completes, telling the Handler to send the reply to the user.

In your case, it should be fairly simple to fix. Instead of storing the Promise in a variable, which you never use, you can just return it with something like this:

```
return carrinho.get()
  .then(doc => {...})
  .catch(err => {...});
```